# Git bash doesn't see git while running arc version

Tags: git, bash, git-extensions, arcanist

I'm trying to run command arc version from git bash that is opened from git extension and this throws me an exception.
[image]

When I'm opening bash.exe directly from C:\Program Files\Git\bin it works fine.[image]

Also when I'm running this from cmd.exe it works. The problem is only when I'm trying to run it from git extension.[image]

What can it be?

Comment: I do no know what is arc. But such situation is possible when (lets to say) arc-server runing in environment where `path` variable does not contain path to git (this mean that your `arc` cmd is client). Or when arc runing in suid environment where `path` variable does not contain path to git. Try to search documentation about arc may be it need special way to comfigure its own `path`. Try to execute shell command (that show path) from your arc if it have such possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long investigation I've discovered that bash terminal has it's own PATH that consist of windows path plus some other bash-related variables. So, before this I've installed sencha, and it added some not existing variables to .bash_profile and that broke my bash.